# libusb Windows using WinUSB BulkTransfer receiving inconsistant

Tags: windows, usb, libusb, winusb

I am attempting to communicate with a custom USB device through windows using libusbx. I have the WinUSB driver installed for the device and am able to get *some* communication to happen. It's just not operating as I expect.

I am trying to get some basic two way communication happening essentially from the PC I send a single byte and expect some number of bytes back. Currently if I reset the device and run my program that sends a byte, I only receive a single byte back. If I re-run my program, I get just the next byte back. This happens a few more times until eventually I receive what I expect.

For example:
PC sends an 'a'

the expected output is

```
buffer[0]=3c
buffer[1]=6c
buffer[2]=0
buffer[3]=3e
```

What I actually get is:

```
//First try
buffer[0]=3c

//Second Try
buffer[0]=6c

//Third Try
buffer[0]=0
buffer[1]=3e

//Fourth+ tries
buffer[0]=3c
buffer[1]=6c
buffer[2]=0
buffer[3]=3e
```

When I test the USB device over a com port using serial communication, everything operates as expected.

Here is a pastebin of the code being ran:
http://pastebin.com/bQtyS6vq

Has anyone experienced similar problems or have any suggestions for a fix?